# Problem with sending attachment (ie.Pdf file) with Email from C# desktop application

Tags: c#

I am sending a `.pdf` file (generated by code & stored in my computer) by email as attachment its working I am able to send it but the issue is I am not able to view it directly in the browser. Browser asks to download pdf which I don't want.

My pdf file path is in a string variable. when I pass this variable to attachment, browser asks to download it but if I pass static path of pdf instead of using variable the pdf gets open directly in browser which I want.

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                // mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("E:\\API_BILL\\TAX INV-10181-API RECHARGE-S G SHINDE.pdf"));
                // above line gives me result as I want want but I want to set filepath dynamically.
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FilePath.ToString(), "fname/pdf");
```

Comment: In the second case you are adding 'fname/pdf' as content type, in the first case not. Anyway the proper content type for pdf should be 'application/pdf'

Comment: thanks for your response. What is 'application'  in your case?? In my case  fname is a string which also contains a file path.

Comment: @Deepali that makes no sense. In your example above, fname is a hard coded string, not a variable. And anyway, that part of the method call us to assign the content type, not the filename. As Elmo says, the correct content type for a PDF should be "application/pdf" literally (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types). The filename is chosen as the same filename as the file you are attaching. But in any case, the filename has nothing to do with the content type.

Comment: Without the correct content type, the browser may not recognise the file type and therefore does not attempt to display it, even though it is capable of doing so

Comment: As for passing the file name dynamically, as long as the file gets attached, it should make no difference to how the mail client eventually displays it. The resulting email doesn't contain any info about how you attached it. I can only assume that maybe your filePath variable maybe didn't contain what you expected.

Comment: @Adyson My FilePath variable has given me "E:\API_BILL\TAX INV-10209-API RECHARGE-A G Jadhav.pdf " which is same as static string format

Comment: @Adyson thanks for your reply. My problem is solved after editing  "attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FilePath.ToString(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);"